# How can I make it difficult to install a new operating system on a certain computer?

Tags: installation, operating-systems

I want to host a website on a desktop computer running Ubuntu with a Windows virtual machine. I will give away the computer in exchange for a number of months of remote web hosting. I want to add some kind of lock (hardware or otherwise) so that the end users will have difficulty just reinstalling Windows and using the machine as they want, in contradiction to the contract.

Ideally, I'd want the machine to die if reinstallation of the OS is attempted. It **doesn't** have to be **completely insurmountable**, but it has to be **difficult enough to prevent casual reinstallation**. Perhaps on bootup the system can check whether certain files exist on the computer and refuse to boot if they do not. I don't know if this is possible, but maybe BIOS is password protected, and searches for files before boot up. The files it looks for could be date sensitive, i.e. require remote replacement on a schedule.

Comment: Do you already own the machine? or will you buy one?

Comment: I will buy.  Open to options.

Comment: Who is going to be doing this hosting for you? If you don't trust them to not wipe the computer, why would you trust them with your website's data?

Comment: Hmm... good point.  I am not hosting sensitive material however.  Also wouldn't password protection be possible to avoid them accessing the material?

Comment: What should it be good for? You're giving a computer away for some time. I can understand you care about the final state of it but WTF do you care about what happens in the meantime?

Comment: It's the golden rule of computer security: if somebody has direct access to the hardware, then any protections you put in place can be defeated. I just don't see why you would want to do this. If they turn off the computer or have any sort of problem with it, your website is suddenly gone. A cheap shared hosting plan is much less expensive than buying a computer would be, and gives you guaranteed uptime, backups, and proper sysadmins.

Comment: To clarify - are you running the webserver on the machine you are giving away, right? Then you are giving somebody the machine, they are hooking it up to the internet, and they get to use it while it serves your files?

Comment: I think the OP does not understand what "Give away" means. Sounds like something Sony would want to do.

Comment: @maaartinus I care about more than just the final state because I may need to update the machine's setup remotely.

Comment: @nhinkle good points. But there would be more than one server for the final result and there would be failover.

Comment: yes I am running the web server on the machine I'm giving away.

Comment: Please don't downvote this just because you don't agree with the idea of locking a computer.  Companies lock cellphones.  People unlock the cellphones.  That's fine with me I'm looking for the same idea.  This question is in the right forum as far as I can tell, if you downvote, please leave a comment here to let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: @D W: If people/companies come here to ask how to lock cellphones, they will be downvoted as well. You're simply doing something that some people don't like about. (Disclaimer: I did NOT vote)

Comment: This is a totally valid _question_ - the need to lock down a computer to prevent the OS from being modified is completely on-topic and there are many good reasons to do so. I personally feel like your ultimate goal is illogical, but it is still a valid question.

Comment: @netvope Thank you for the explanation. I understand why this forum shouldn be tech support for Big Business.  However, if there is a clear, concise, unique, directed, computer-related question, I think it should not matter who is asking or why.

Comment: I think it is a good question, clearly and politely explained, on-topic and with much response of the OP to comment all the answers. Even id the answer is now you can't I can't see a reason why to down-vote, all the opposite: +1.

Comment: **My thoughts** I want to host a website on a desktop computer running Ubuntu with a Windows virtual machine. **Fantastic!** I will give away the computer in exchange for a number of months of remote web hosting. **So you have the webserver but want to give it away?** I want to add some kind of lock (hardware or otherwise) so that the end users will have difficulty just reinstalling Windows and using the machine as they want, in contradiction to the contract. **You're making this a lot harder than it needs to be.. why not just _keep_ the computer??**

Comment: @aqua I understand this doesn't make too much sense to others.  If it helps think of it as me trying to play with remote hosting and failover.  I will have one computer with me serving pages on a cheap DSL connection but what if my internet goes down, or my power goes out?  This project will allow me to have another computer(s) at a remote location to act as a failover at little cost and 100% control.

Comment: @DW.  I removed my answer about tampering with the MBR because you are right: Windows installation has no regard for existing boot loaders and overrides the MBR with its own loader.

Comment: @Alain: ok thanks for attempting a solution anyways! :)

Comment: @nhinkle: that is a good thought about the cheap shared hosting plan, but that solution doesn't have the control I need.  There are few such plans with root access and sufficient dedicated ram. Sometimes there is red tape to get anything done.  Uptime guarantees are discussed here http://whreviews.com/the-uptime-guarantee.htm

Comment: @DW, I could point out an immense number of flaws in your plan, but you seem to be convinced. I'm going to stop arguing, because we're polluting this question. If you truly believe this is the most cost-effective and reliable method to host your files, then I wish you the best of luck in making it work.

Comment: The only solution to this is legal, not technical. But why would you entrust your hardware let alone your data to a party you thought might tamper with it? And what are you hosting? Apparently it's so important that you need a remote failover with six 9's yet you seem far more concerned about a few hundred dollars worth of hardware. Surely a VPS provider like Linode or Slicehost is more likely to give the service you need than some clowns you already suspect will re-roll your box as soon as you leave the carpark.

Comment: @nhinkle @bitslave: maybe I need to rethink whether this is the best strategy.  I'm not saying I know more than you guys, I'm just trying to defend what my logic was at the time.

Comment: I'm a student, Linode's monthy cost of $20 before tax hurts my wallet more than buying a used computer and fixing it up and giving it away to get at least a year's hosting and maybe two.  I suppose six 9's is less important than load balancing.  Besides, are you really saying that two cheap DSL connections at two peoples homes with failover give six 9's?  Sometimes when I go to bed or move stuff around my room I accidentally hit the switch on my power bar.

Comment: I wouldn't expect move from someone else I made a deal with, accidents happen.  These are not professional operations (as I'm sure you can tell :) ).  In addition to small business websites of friends, I'd like to host websites that run bioinformatics applications, and maybe a storage site for me and my friends.

Comment: Since this _is_ a valid question about how to prevent a different OS from being installed, I think the best solution might be this: leave this question here, reword it to just be about how to lock down a computer without going into all the details about why that were so controversial, then create a _new_ post (possibly on server fault, as they deal more with servers) about the best way to achieve your ultimate goal of serving files and sites as you need.

Comment: @nhinkle: That is a great suggestion.  I've gotten a bit busy at work but once some of my time frees up again I will do that and post that link here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The only tools you have for preventing installation of a new operating system on standard PC hardware would be to do something like this:

- Lock the case.  Use the Kensington slot if your case has one, otherwise physically lock it somehow.
- Configure a BIOS setup password.
- Configure BIOS to boot only off of first hard drive, to not boot off any external USB device, LAN, or CD-ROM.  Ship the computer without a CD-ROM and/or floppy if possible.  Internally disconnect or epoxy USB ports.
- I'm not sure if you can configure GRUB to never boot from an external drive, but if it's possible, GRUB should be configured this way.
- Select good root and user passwords.

Of course, if they physically open the case, you can't do much, but this should prevent casual reinstallation of another operating system.

Comment: +1 Yes preventing casual reinstallation is what i want to do.  I would like a method that allows CD-ROM and USB usage though.  No one wants a computer without a CD-ROM.

Comment: Then ship it with a CD-ROM/floppy, but without the CD-ROM or floppy connected to the motherboard.

Comment: That is not helpful to me and doesn't solve the problem.  Nice try though.

Comment: @D W  Actually what he said covers you.   He said "Ship the computer without a CD-ROM and/or floppy if possible"  So, what if not possible? Look at the sentence he wrote before that, it says "Configure BIOS to boot only off of first hard drive, to not boot off any external USB device, LAN, or CD-ROM"

Comment: @barlop you are right.  I thought ultrasawblade was being sarcastic with his last comment but I need to reexamine this answer.

Comment: @D W: they can still use the USB/CD-Rom but just can't both from it !

Comment: @Omeid Herat: hmm... yes that would solve the problem I believe. If no USB/CD-ROM boot was possible and no USB epoxy was necessary then I think it would work for my purposes.

Comment: I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer just to see if any other potential solutions develop.  I was thinking about asking a follow up question.  Whether there is a way to make a computer die if it doesn't get internet connection for a few days.  I fear there will be even more backlash if I post that question though.

Comment: I suppose I could achieve that with scripts on the ubuntu partition and be fairly confident the end user couldn't remove or disable the script.  Maybe.

Comment: @D W You could make it turn off with a script of some kind.But even in theory you wouldn't make it die.u could write a  script that wipes everything.I heard that maybe around 20 years ago monitors had an issue and could be turned on and off by a program and then broke, maybe exploded or smoke came out.But that was a long time ago.It's unusual to be able to do something in a program that literally kills a component.That's the only case i've heard of.There is such a thing as a floppy disk bomb, but I dont know anybody that got that working,and it might not be explosive enough to kill the MBRD

Comment: @D W If you just stopped windows loading which is possible, just moving some important files out.. malware seems to manage it! then, well, you'd want to stop safe mode too. Or if you just wiped the drive or deleted the partition.. Then with your other lockdowns working, BIOS password and the physical lock, they wouldn't be able to use the computer unless they got through/around those.

Comment: If the computer is powerless, it can't do anything, if it stays so for several days. You have to lock the case to prevent somebody from switching the harddrive, you have to lock the bios and tell grub to prevent from taken parameters. In addition you have to check, that no BIOS-Master-password has been leaked for that particular bios (Award-2.34.x, Phoenix-1.23.y or whatever). A lockable case normally only enables you to detect fraud afterwards - it will not put much resistance to damaging force.

Comment: *"tell grub to prevent from taken parameters"* - You don't need grub for such a system, do you?

Answer (score 29):

If you are giving someone physical access to a machine, there is **nothing** that you can do to stop them.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm trying to avoid casual reinstallation.

Comment: @D W - you can reset a BIOS password by moving a jumper on most motherboards. It would take someone 10 minutes to google it, 5 minutes to cut the lock and 2 minutes to remove the BIOS password. Really, there's no good way.

Comment: That would be a sufficient barrier for my purposes. That is sufficiently difficult.

Comment: @D W - so you asked this question so that someone could tell you to put a lock on it?

Comment: No, they need to be able to use usb and cd without being able to reinstall the operating system very easily.  Can you solve that problem?

Comment: +1 to this answer. There is no such thing as "casual installation" - anyone approaching your box with a boot cd will have it up and running the os of their choose quick smart. The best that any of the suggestions on this page will do is to prevent "accidental installation", whatever that may be.

Comment: @D W - You need to define "easily" then. To someone that wants to reinstall an OS, snipping a lock on the case and moving a jumper is pretty easy. I think many users on this site would be able to do that without even looking up which jumper to move. This sounds like you issue is more easily solved at a policy level, and not a technical level since it's literally impossible to solve at a technical level.

Comment: @markM In theory "To someone that wants to reinstall an OS, snipping a lock on the case and moving a jumper is pretty easy" and that may be true to you.  However, doing so is much scarier and daunting to the average user than popping in a Windows CD.  The vast majority of the population does not follow sites like superuser.com. Which would your grandma rather do?

Comment: My grandma wouldn't be popping in a windows cd in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to replace any visible screws with security Torx, especially the screws holding the hard drive in place.  That way they can't install another OS on a different hard drive, swap out the hard drive, then boot from the new hard drive.  Anyone can buy security Torx drivers, but it'll slow down a normal person, who probably won't have any in their toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few Dell computers that need an administrator password to boot from anything other than the Hard Drive. The downside being that if the CMOS battery is removed for 30 seconds, they would then be able to bypass any previously set BIOS settings as they are all completely restored. But that is just my 2 cents. Unless the person you are giving this too really knows that much about resetting the BIOS just to install Windows, then don't give them a computer, but otherwise, this can prevent casual installation.

Comment: +1 This is the first answer that approaches a solution.  Do you have more information about this?

Comment: That is a usual BIOS feature, nothing special to DELL machines. Corporate PC often have a funny little lock to prevent you from removing the CMOS battery or doing other things (hardware keylogger, ...). They don't resist pure force, but you would recognize it afterwards, if they were broken.

Comment: I mentioned the Dell machines due to my experience with using a BIOS lock on them. Obviously must be a feature that is used widely in a corporate setting.

Answer (score 2):

Do what most companies do, make them sign a contract saying that you refuse to support it if they change the operating system.

Comment: Thank you for your two cents.  The end user will not need much support.  This will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

- Set the BIOS to boot off the hard drive first (that removes the ability to boot from USB/CD-ROM)
- Set a BIOS password
- Make sure the OS user doesn't have admin privileges (i.e. so that they can't pop in an installation CD while in Windows/Linux and do it from there).

This should give you the security level it seems you are after.

Comment: You need to harden GRUB(2) too. Maybe you recognized that he told it will be an Ubuntu-PC with virtual Windows.

Comment: This answer is similar to the one http://superuser.com/questions/246234/how-can-i-make-it-difficult-to-install-a-new-operating-system-on-a-certain-comput/246250#246250.  I will focus on that one for now.

Answer (score 1):

To the question from the comments:

> Whether there is a way to make a computer die if it doesn't get internet connection for a few days.

Yes, possible, but only on a casual basis, and vulnerable to networking problems.

You may put a script into the init-script section, which checks for internetaccess, and does a `shutdown` if there is no access.

More elaborated scripts could write to a protocol, or access a website based on the date.

If the user has superuser privileges, he might detect the script, remove it, deactivate it and manipulate it in all ways.

Therefore you have to disable 'rescue'-mode in grub, and disable the possibility to modify grub by interruption on boot.

If the user encounters random network problems, the machine might shutdown unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

As a hardware option, you could go with is a secure computer case. I purchased [this case](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=627446) ages ago (it's no longer available, but gives you an idea for what you're looking for). It's got a locking front door, and a locking side panel (the other side panel is riveted on, does not come off). Basically, if it's all locked up, all you can access is the rear connectors and a few front-panel connectors (two usb, one firewire400). There's no access to the drives, power button, or reset button. The actual locking tab is only plastic, so I'm sure it could be broken with enough force, but you're not looking for CIA-grade security here. It should be enough to discourage them.

Comment: Just to let you know, FireWire allows direct DMA access.